# Good resources about Volatility Calibration with code Snippet

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, calibration, local-volatility, volatility-smile

As I just landed in the quantitative finance world, I would like to dig deeper into Volatility Surfaces construction.
I have a good theoritical background ( I'm familiar with volatility models ) but I've never conducted a computational study of a volatility surface calibration.
I would like to know if there's good resources, more computationally oriented, to put a step into this world ( Calibrating a local volatility fct, retrieving the break even, doing the work for different volatility models ... )

Lot of thanks :)